# Error connecting via SSH to Bitbucket using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh

I'm a beginner with `Rails`, `Git` and `Capistrano` trying to deploy my first app.

I've setup a VPS with `Ubuntu`, `Nginx` and `Unicorn` installed and now whish to deploy using `Capistrano`. My app is stored in a `Bitbucket` repository.

In order to check if I correctly set up `Capistrano` I ran the following command.

`$ cap production git:check` and 
`$ cap production deploy:check`

These however, gave me the following error:

```
INFO [c65cf8c7] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/testapp/ as developer@[IP]
DEBUG [c65cf8c7] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/testapp/
Text will be echoed in the clear. Please install the HighLine or Termios libraries to suppress echoed text.
developer@[IP]'s password: [password]
INFO [c65cf8c7] Finished in 31.340 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
DEBUG Uploading /tmp/testapp/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
INFO Uploading /tmp/testapp/git-ssh.sh 100.0%
INFO [2dbfc686] Running /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/testapp/git-ssh.sh as developer@[IP]
DEBUG [2dbfc686] Command: /usr/bin/env chmod +x /tmp/testapp/git-ssh.sh
INFO [2dbfc686] Finished in 0.017 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
INFO [b0c6add8] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:[USER]/testapp.git as developer@[IP]
DEBUG [b0c6add8] Command: ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/testapp/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:[USER]/testapp.git )
DEBUG [b0c6add8]        Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.143.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
DEBUG [b0c6add8]        Error reading response length from authentication socket.
DEBUG [b0c6add8]        Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG [b0c6add8]        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as developer@[IP]: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.143.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Error reading response length from authentication socket.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128
git stdout: Nothing written
git stderr: Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,104.192.143.3' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Error reading response length from authentication socket.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Tasks: TOP => git:check
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It seems like something goes wrong with the SSH-authentication, Standard git commands as `push` or `pull` to my git repository work fine.

Grom my local machine `$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.com` tells me:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.7' to the list of known hosts.
logged in as [USER].  
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

From my `developer@vps` account: `ssh -T git@bitbucket.com`

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.7' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any idea's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano tries to checkout the git repository **at the deploy target**, i.e. at the VPS. Thus, you need to get the ssh connection to bitbucket working from the VPS machine.

I guess your ssh identities are different at your local host and the VPS and that you have only configured the local-machine ssh key in bitbucket.

Can you compare `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on your local machine and while logged as `developer` at your VPS? If the keys are different, you need to add the public ssh key (the `id_rsa.pub` file) from the VPS to the bitbucket configuration, so that you can connect to bitbucket from your VPS using ssh.

Comment: Thanks. That's it. I'm still getting the error: `Error reading response length from authentication socket`, but it now finishes succesfully. Cheers!